# How to replace a special pattern in a string?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a very long string that represents several rows like this:

```
'''
if (x<= 2.640065550804138)
{
    if (y<= -1.0)
    {
        return "Up and Down";
    }
    else // if (y> -1.0)
    {
        return "None";
    }
}
else // if (x> 2.640065550804138)
{
    return "None";
}
'''
```

and I want to go over that string and replace every occurrence of a substring that looks like this

```
'''
{
    <Some line>
}
'''
```

with

```
'''
    <Some line>
'''
```

Basically remove the brackets if only one line is between them.
How do I do that preferably in an efficient way?
(If it's confusing, the string contains "code" in c# format.)

Comment: Question is not clear. what do you want to do with the line outside the brackets?, do you need indentations?, do you mean the output is like python syntax? 
I answered the question with your current explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import io

str_value = """if (x<= 2.640065550804138)
{
   if (y<= -1.0)
   {
      return "Up and Down";
   }
   else // if (y> -1.0)
   {
      return "None";
   }
}
else // if (x> 2.640065550804138)
{
   return "None";
}"""

OPEN_BRACE = "{"
CLOSE_BRACE = "}"

lines = list()
with io.StringIO(str_value) as stream:
  for line in stream:
    #we dont want empty strings in between.
    if not line.isspace():
        lines.append(line)

modified_lines = list()
idx = 0
while idx  <  len(lines):
  line = lines[idx]
  #check there is line between '{' and '}' brace.
  if line.strip() == OPEN_BRACE and lines[idx + 2].strip() == CLOSE_BRACE :
    modified_lines.append(lines[idx + 1])
    idx += 2
  else:
    modified_lines.append(lines[idx])
  idx += 1

  mod = ''.join(modified_lines)
  print(mod)
```

The output is:

```
if (x<= 2.640065550804138)
{
   if (y<= -1.0)
      return "Up and Down";
   else // if (y> -1.0)
      return "None";
}
else // if (x> 2.640065550804138)
   return "None";
```

Beware - this will remove the braces for all such constructs, however I think you are looking to re-format a code file using this for if / else blocks, so you might have to do an extra check that when you start the check for brace it should be for if or else statements etc..

Good Luck.

Comment: This looks okay, but Isn't there a more pythonic solution? And no, I do not have to check if the braces are for an if/else block.

Comment: Since we are literally parsing the text and would want to remove empty lines between the  braces, one would need to step through the lines and also preserve the original formatting as you would just want to remove the braces as such.  Also I understand pythonic is to do with making code more readable rather than - less lines of code...